# PHP 1 image for every 5 amount

Tags: php

I need to assign 1 image to every 5 people in the array using foreach and a forloop

```php
<?php
$clubs["Example 1"] = 25;
$clubs["Example 2"] = 12;
$clubs["Example 3"] = 34;
$clubs["Example 4"] = 10;

foreach()
```

does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You need to be more clear and precise what the integers stand for.

Comment: I'll use $clubs for the integers

Comment: Very unclear what you actually want here. Please show a proper example of the given input data, and what exactly the expected result is.

Comment: Apologies, english isn't my first language so I'll try my best to explain:
I need to make a list that shows the names of the clubs (in this case the examples) and 1 icon for every 5 people in the club (put right after the name of the club). All clubs already have assigned amounts.

Comment: So divide the amount by five, and use floor or ceil to make the result an integer. (Whether floor or ceil, depends on whether for 12 people, you want to show two or three images.) And then just generate that amount of icons after the club name in your output logic - via a loop, or `str_repeat`.

Comment: could you show me an example? I'm not experienced at all and i've tried to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Result: https://extendsclass.com/php-bin/b431455

```
<?php

$personsPerIcon = 5;
$icon = [
    "url" => "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/456/456212.png",
    "size" => "15px"
];
$clubs = [
    [
        "name" => "Manchester",
        "persons" => 25,
    ], [
        "name" => "PSG",
        "persons" => 12
    ], [
        "name" => "Madrid",
        "persons" => 34
    ], [
        "name" => "Bayern",
        "persons" => 10
    ]
];

foreach ($clubs as $i => $club) {
    $clubs[$i]["icons"] = floor($club["persons"] / $personsPerIcon);
}

?>


<ul>
    <?php foreach ($clubs as $club) : ?>
        <li>
            <?= str_repeat(
                '<img src="' . $icon["url"] . '" width="' . $icon["size"] . '">',
                $club["icons"]
            ) ?>
            <?= $club["name"] . ' (' . $club["persons"] . ') ' ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Based on @CBroe comment

Comment: Is there a way I can use forloops instead?

Comment: You'll need to replace `foreach($clubs as $club){ ... }` by `for($i = 0; $i < count($clubs); $i++){ //... ; $i++; }` and use `$clubs[$i]` instead of `$club` inside the loop. `foreach` looks much easier to me in this case.